# MA Residuals in R using arima()

Tags: time-series, arima

I fit a MA(1) model using arima() in R:

```
set.seed(100)
y = arima.sim(list(ma=c(-.6)),n=100)
fit=arima(y, order=c(0,0,1), include.mean = FALSE)
```

The model being fit is 
$y_t = w_t + \theta w_{t-1}$

Fitted should be 
$\hat{y}_t = \theta w_{t-1}$
and 
residuals returned by `residuals()` is
$y_t-\hat{y}_t$
and should be $w_t$.
We should be able to recover the fitted values with
$\theta w_{t-1}$.

This is the case for t large but not t small with the fitted() function used on the arima fitted MA(1) object.

```
wt=residuals(fit)
cbind(coef(fit)[1]*wt[1:99],fitted(fit)[2:100])
```

Here are the residuals 2:5 and 95:100.

```
[2,] -0.03791725  0.02166335
[3,] -0.72713403 -0.67625895
[4,] -0.20811367 -0.19194927

[96,]  0.42251544  0.42251544
[97,] -0.39087306 -0.39087306
[98,]  0.82550957  0.82550957
[99,]  1.02984053  1.02984053
```

I assume it has to do with how the MA(1) is translated to a state-space model to be fitted by the Kalman filter.